# virtual enviroment is set to python 2.6 but yet installing packages in 2.7

Tags: python, virtualenv

I used the following to create my virtual environment.

```
mkvirtualenv myenv --no-site-packages -p /usr/bin/python2.6
```

When I am in the virtual environment I can see that I am using python2.6 even though the default for the system is 2.7 on ubuntu 11.10.

So, I run python setup.py install for a package and there are being installed in python2.7 site packages.  Note, the package I install in in-turn runs easy_install to install dependancies.

e.g.

```
Using /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7
Searching for nltk==2.0.1
Best match: nltk 2.0.1
Processing nltk-2.0.1-py2.7.egg
nltk 2.0.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
```

How do I create a pure virtual environment for python?

Answer (score 0):

If you use active script and its doesnt work properly. Try to install packages directly, like:

```
/virtualenv/bin/pip install package
```

This is a 100% nice work solution.
And when you want start your application from virtualenv you could:

```
/virtualenv/bin/python your_project.py
```